# How to add polylines to this particular Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

Can someone help me with what I need to add and where so I can make polylines between Markers for my journey on my site. Thanks in advance. I try to figure out by myself and I didn't sucseed. If anyone can tell me it would be very nice.

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
    {
        "title": 'Nusay Hotel, Ashgabat',
        "lat": '37.9293938',
        "lng": '58.3841203',
        "description": 'DAY 01 - DAY 03 Arrive ASHGABAT We are cordially welcomed upon arrival at Ashgabat Airport and then transferred to our hotel. Balance of the day is free at leisure. An ex Soviet state, Turkmenistan is a one party state. Ashgabat, relatively a very small city, offers very interesting sites to see. Resource rich Turkmens have invested in beautifying their capital with a lot of marble of immense size and shapes. Ashgabat was recently noted by the Guinness Book of World Records as having the highest number of white marble-clad buildings in the world - 543 new buildings lined with white marble covering a total area of 4.5 million square meters. DAY 02 ASHGABAT Our study into the heritage of Central Asia starts as we explore the Parthian Fortresses of Nisa*. The site is of one of the earliest and most important cities of the Parthian Empire, a major power from the mid-3rd century BC to the 3rd century AD.  Archaeological excavations in two parts of the site have revealed richly decorated architecture, illustrative of domestic, state and religious functions. Situated at the crossroads of important commercial and strategic axes, this powerful empire formed a barrier to Roman expansion while serving as an important communication and trading centre between east and west, north and south. We then head to theSpiritual Mosque, one of the biggest mosques in Central Asia, visit the National Museum of History and continue to Arch of Neutrality. In the afternoon we drive to GeokDepe to visit Arkadash stud farm (subject to opening) to see Akhalteke horses, the pride of Turkmen nation. Our tour concludes with visits to Presidential Square, ErtogrulGhazy Mosque, drive through some of the marble structures and the newly built Independence Park. Dinner tonight will be at the Poytagt Restaurant introducing us to food and cuisines of Central Asia. DAY 03 ASHGABAT/MARY/ASHGABAT An early morning short flight gets us to Mary to visit the State Historical and Cultural Park Ancient Merv*, which is the oldest and best-preserved of the oasis-cities along the Silk Route in Central Asia. The remains in this vast oasis span 4,000 years of human history. A number of monuments are still visible, particularly from the last two millennia, such as the Sultan Sanjar Mausoleum, the Large and Small Gyz Gala, Erk Gala, Gyaur Gala, Keshk Fortress, among others. On our way back to Mary we visit an artist’s home to see a demonstration of carpet weaving, embroidery, painting, cooking of local bread. After lunch we take our flight back to Ashgabat. Evening free.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'JipekJoli Hotel, Nukus',
        "lat": '42.465825',
        "lng": '59.607718',
        "description": 'DAY 04 After a short flight to Dashoguz we head to Kunya-Urgench*, situated in on the left bank of the Amu Daria River.  The old town contains a series of monuments mainly from the 11th to 16th centuries, including a mosque, the gates of a caravanserai, fortresses, mausoleums and a 60-m high minaret. The monuments testify to outstanding achievements in architecture and craftsmanship whose influence reached Iran and Afghanistan, and later the architecture of the Mogul Empire of 16th-century India. After our visit of KunyaUrgench we drive to the Turkmenistan-Uzbekistan border point at Khojeyli, where we go through border formalities on both checkpoints, whilst being an interesting experience they do lack modern facilities.  A short drive viewing the countryside gets us to Nukus – a place that is almost lost in the middle of the desert.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Grand Abdi Malik Hotel, Khiva',
        "lat": '41.377115',
        "lng": '60.3580361',
        "description": 'DAY 05 Morning we visit the SavitskyKarakalpakstan Art Museum, which hosts the worlds second largest collection of Russian avant-garde art applied arts objects. It is also home to one of the largest collections of archeological objects and folk, applied and contemporary art originating from Central Asia. Drive through rural Uzbekistan to the historical city of Khiva. Here we explore the Ichan-Kala - the inner town (protected by brick walls some 10 m high) of the old Khiva oasis, which was the last resting-place of caravans before crossing the desert to Iran. Although few very old monuments still remain, it is a coherent and well-preserved example of the Muslim architecture of Central Asia. There are several outstanding structures such as the Djuma Mosque, the mausoleums and the madrasas and the two magnificent palaces built at the beginning of the 19th century by Alla-Kulli-Khan. Dinner at the popular Yassaulbashi restaurant.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Omar Khayyam Hotel, Bukhara',
        "lat": '39.7703649',
        "lng": '64.4149347',
        "description": 'DAY 06 - DAY 07 A short drive to Urgench the capital of Khorezm province. It has a population of 150,000 inhabitants. We will have a drive through of the city before talking our flight to the historical Silk Road city of Bukhara. Upon arrival at Bukhara the most well known of the Silk Road oasis dating back to over 2,000 years. It is the most complete example of a medieval city in Central Asia, with an urban fabric that has remained largely intact. Monuments of particular interest include the famous tomb of Ismail Samani, a masterpiece of 10th-century Muslim architecture, and a large number of 17th-century madrasas. Afternoon we enjoy a walking tour of Bukhara, visiting several mosques, madrasas and the hat seller’s market. Evening we enjoy a folklore show at the Devanbegi Madrasa. End the day the Bukharan style with dinner enjoying Bukharan cuisine at the Minzifa Restaurant located in the Old Town. DAY 07 Today we continue our tour through the Historic Centre of Bukhara*, which houses over 140 architectural monuments. Bukhara had narrow streets will remind us of the Arabian Nights. After seeing the historical sites we visit Akbar’s Gallery where one can seea rich collection of old carpets and suzzane – his display center is like a museum assisted by UNESCO – his collection is well known to the Metropolitan Museum.   To culminate our Bukhara experience we visit a miniaturist house where we see the workshop of the painters and his students all trying to retain the traditional art. Miniature painting was introduced here from Persia and the same tradition continued for many years but is facing its challenges with modernity.   We join in for a home cooked meal.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Grand Samarkand Hotel, Samarkand',
        "lat": '39.6725002',
        "lng": '66.9364854',
        "description": 'DAY 08 - DAY 09 Yet another tour of the historical city visiting the SitoraiMokhi-Khosa Palace followed by the residence of the Emir of Bukhara, the Mausoleum of the Sufi BakhoutdinNaqshbandi and the ChorBakr Necropolis. As we continue to Samarkand we stop atGijduvon to visit a famous madrassa built by Ulugh Beg the Timurid Sultan, astronomer and mathematician. We also visit the tomb and memorial of the prominent philosopher AbduholikGijduvoni, after whom the city is named.  An interesting insight to the arts of Uzbekistan as we visit the famous pottery works of Alisher well known for his unique style and color. Past famous visitors include Prince Charles, Lady Diana and Hillary Clinton.  Arrival Samarkand late afternoon. Evening, after some free time to stroll through the lanes of this historical city we are treated to dinner at the famous Old City Restaurant of Samarkand. DAY 09 This day is dedicated to explore the Historic town of Samarkand* - a crossroad and melting pot of the worlds cultures. Founded in the 7th century B.C. as ancient Afrasiab, Samarkand had its most significant development in the Timurid period from the 14th to the 15th centuries. The major monuments include the Registan Mosque and madrasas, Bibi-Khanum Mosque, the Shakhi-Zinda compound and the Gur-Emir ensemble, as well as Ulugh-Begs Observatory. Time permitting we visit a family home to learn how the most popular Uzbek meal, the pulao, is cooked. Evening is free and you may visit the local Afghan carpet makers, the local winery, the Kunhil paper makers or just back into time.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'ShakreSabz Star Hotel, Shakhrisyabz',
        "lat": '39.0400391',
        "lng": '66.8069597',
        "description": 'DAY 10 Morning we tour the Afrosiyob Museum and the tomb of Saint Daniel. Then we drive to KoniGhil village to see the traditional way of making Samarkand paper from mulberry leaves.   Continue to the Historic Centre of Shakhrisyabz*, the birthplace of Tamerlane. The city contains a collection of exceptional monuments and ancient quarters that bear witness to the citys secular development, and particularly to the period of its apogee, under the rule of Amir Temur and the Temurids, in the 15th-16th century. Dinner will be a local experience at Alisher’s House. Evening free.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Serena Hotel, Dushanbe',
        "lat": '38.5142164',
        "lng": '68.7511861',
        "description": 'DAY 11 - DAY 12 An early morning departure as we drive to the capital city of Tajikistan. Upon arrival at the border we first complete exit border formalities of Uzbekistan and then a short walk across to the Tajik side to do the entry border formalities. Change of vehicles as we drive to Dushanbe.  We arrive at Dushanbe and are transferred to our hotel. Tajikistan is a double landlocked country, which was part of the Soviet Union and now has a Presidential form of government. It has a population of 8 million.  Evening we are treated to Turkish/Tajik local cuisine dinner at the Café Merve Turkish. DAY 12 Our day in Dushanbe is spent visiting the National Museum of Tajikistan, the Gurminj Musical Instruments Museum, Statue of Ismail Samani and Rudaki Park. Subject to permit we also visit the recently built and an architectural marvel, the IsmailiJamatkhan and Centre.  Lunch is at the Traktir Restaurant known for its speciality of Ukranian cuisine. We then visit the Botanical Gardens and culminate with an experience of the local bazaar. Evening is free to stroll the street and meet the friendly Tajiks at the teahouses.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Lotte Hotel, Tashkent',
        "lat": '41.309827',
        "lng": '69.2665513',
        "description": 'DAY 13 We explore Uzbekistan’s capital visiting the Old City, including the Khast-Imom Complex where the world famous Quran of Caliph Uthman/Ottoman has been preserved, the Madrasah of Barak-Khan, Tilla Sheikh Mosque, the Mausoleum of the Saint Abu BakrKaffalShashi, the Islamic Institute of Imam al-Bukhari and explore Chor-Su Bazaar. An evening flight gets us to the largest and until recently the capital city of Kazakhstan. Upon arrival at Alma Aty we are welcomed and transferred to our hotel.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Otrar Hotel, Almaty',
        "lat": '43.2608189',
        "lng": '76.9495966',
        "description": 'DAY 14 An early morning departure as we drive to the capital city of Tajikistan. Upon arrival at the border we first complete exit border formalities of Uzbekistan and then a short walk across to the Tajik side to do the entry border formalities. Change of vehicles as we drive to Dushanbe.  We arrive at Dushanbe and are transferred to our hotel. Tajikistan is a double landlocked country, which was part of the Soviet Union and now has a Presidential form of government. It has a population of 8 million.  Evening we are treated to Turkish/Tajik local cuisine dinner at the Café Merve Turkish.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Ak-Keme Hotel, Bishkek',
        "lat": '42.8375965',
        "lng": '74.5818513',
        "description": 'DAY 15 We start early today on what is going to be a long day. Our tour begins with a visit to the Panfilov Park, followed by Zenkov Cathedral, St. Nicholas Cathedral and the Green Bazaar. From here we drive through Chang an-Tianshan Corridor*. We visit the Petroglyphs within the Archaeological Landscape of Tamgaly*. Set around the lush Tamgaly Gorge, amidst the vast, arid Chu-Ili Mountains, is a remarkable concentration of some 5,000 petroglyphs (rock carvings) dating from the second half of the second millennium BC to the beginning of the 20th century. Distributed among 48 complexes with associated settlements and burial grounds, they are testimonies to the husbandry, social organization and rituals of pastoral peoples. From here we drive to the border to Kyrgyzstan and continue to our hotel in Bishkek. Known alsos as Furunze, Bishkek is the capital city of Kyrgyzstan. Lunch will be at the Arzu Restaurant.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Four Seasons Karven Resort, IssykKul Lake',
        "lat": '42.6035605',
        "lng": '76.936764',
        "description": 'DAY 16 - DAY 18 We enjoy our tour of Bishkek, which includes visits to Oak Park, Ala-Too Square, Statue of Manas, the Philharmonic Hall and Victory Monument. Drive to Balasagun and visit the historical Burana Tower*, which dates back to the 9th century AD. We will also visit the nearby museum. We then proceed eastwards into the mountains to Cholpon-Ata where we visit the local rock drawings of the Bronze periods, the local museum and a small local bazaar before arriving at our resort at Central Asia’s most popular will known resort. The Four Season’s Karven is known also for its impressive views of the imposing alpine ranges of the Tian Shan across the lake. For the balance of the day we have optional opportunities to walk around the valley and enjoy some of the boat rides being offered at the enchanting IssykKul Lake. Evening we enjoy dinner at a local restaurant attached to the Lake. DAY 17 Morning we visit the Preshevalsky Museum and Monument on the eastern edge of the Lake. A landmark museum, dedicated to the memory of Nikolai MichailovichPreshevalsky, who was an enthusiastic explorer accredited for his excellent works on the flora and fauna of the region. In the afternoon we visit the Annanaeva village where we get the opportunity to hike and visit local families and see their yurt accommodation and enjoy soup and tea with them. Evening for dinner we taste the cuisine of yet another of the popular restaurants at the IssykKul Lake. DAY 18 Enjoy our time at the lake. Afternoon we drive to Bishkek and enjoy a farewell dinner at Captain Nemo Restaurant.  We are then transferred to the airport and after an enjoyable trail following the Central Asian portion of the Silk Road, we bid farewell to the land of the Stans.'
    },
    ];
        window.onload = function () {
            LoadMap();
        }
        function LoadMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                // zoom: 8, //Not required.
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

            //Create LatLngBounds object.
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);

                //Extend each marker's position in LatLngBounds object.
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            }

            //Get the boundaries of the Map.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            //Center map and adjust Zoom based on the position of all markers.
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        }
    </script>
    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Comment: related question: [linking markers together using a line: google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655257/linking-markers-together-using-a-line-google-maps-api)

Comment: related question: [How to add polylines with an array of position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406355/how-to-add-polylines-with-an-array-of-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markers array is one too long for a single directions request, but the first two points are joined by a flight so you can remove that from the request and draw that as a straight, "as the crow flies" polyline for that, then use the directions service for the remaining locations.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vzvcwuLv/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  //Create LatLngBounds object.
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var request = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    geodesic: true,
    path: [new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng), new google.maps.LatLng(markers[1].lat, markers[1].lng)],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: {
        path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        scale: 4
      },
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '20px'
    }],
  })
  var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    map: map
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);

    //Extend each marker's position in LatLngBounds object.
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

    if (i == 1) {
      request.origin = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
    } else if (i == markers.length - 1) {
      request.destination = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
    } else if (i != 0) {
      if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
      if (request.waypoints.length < 8) {
        request.waypoints.push({
          location: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng),
          stopover: true
        });
      } else {
        alert("too many waypoints, dropping marker number " + i);
      }
    }
  }
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  })
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var markers = [{
  "title": 'Nusay Hotel, Ashgabat',
  "lat": '37.9293938',
  "lng": '58.3841203',
  "description": 'DAY 01 - DAY 03 Arrive ASHGABAT We are cordially welcomed upon arrival at Ashgabat Airport and then transferred to our hotel. Balance of the day is free at leisure. An ex Soviet state, Turkmenistan is a one party state. Ashgabat, relatively a very small city, offers very interesting sites to see. Resource rich Turkmens have invested in beautifying their capital with a lot of marble of immense size and shapes. Ashgabat was recently noted by the Guinness Book of World Records as having the highest number of white marble-clad buildings in the world - 543 new buildings lined with white marble covering a total area of 4.5 million square meters. DAY 02 ASHGABAT Our study into the heritage of Central Asia starts as we explore the Parthian Fortresses of Nisa*. The site is of one of the earliest and most important cities of the Parthian Empire, a major power from the mid-3rd century BC to the 3rd century AD.  Archaeological excavations in two parts of the site have revealed richly decorated architecture, illustrative of domestic, state and religious functions. Situated at the crossroads of important commercial and strategic axes, this powerful empire formed a barrier to Roman expansion while serving as an important communication and trading centre between east and west, north and south. We then head to theSpiritual Mosque, one of the biggest mosques in Central Asia, visit the National Museum of History and continue to Arch of Neutrality. In the afternoon we drive to GeokDepe to visit Arkadash stud farm (subject to opening) to see Akhalteke horses, the pride of Turkmen nation. Our tour concludes with visits to Presidential Square, ErtogrulGhazy Mosque, drive through some of the marble structures and the newly built Independence Park. Dinner tonight will be at the Poytagt Restaurant introducing us to food and cuisines of Central Asia. DAY 03 ASHGABAT/MARY/ASHGABAT An early morning short flight gets us to Mary to visit the State Historical and Cultural Park Ancient Merv*, which is the oldest and best-preserved of the oasis-cities along the Silk Route in Central Asia. The remains in this vast oasis span 4,000 years of human history. A number of monuments are still visible, particularly from the last two millennia, such as the Sultan Sanjar Mausoleum, the Large and Small Gyz Gala, Erk Gala, Gyaur Gala, Keshk Fortress, among others. On our way back to Mary we visit an artist’s home to see a demonstration of carpet weaving, embroidery, painting, cooking of local bread. After lunch we take our flight back to Ashgabat. Evening free.'
}, {
  "title": 'JipekJoli Hotel, Nukus',
  "lat": '42.465825',
  "lng": '59.607718',
  "description": 'DAY 04 After a short flight to Dashoguz we head to Kunya-Urgench*, situated in on the left bank of the Amu Daria River.  The old town contains a series of monuments mainly from the 11th to 16th centuries, including a mosque, the gates of a caravanserai, fortresses, mausoleums and a 60-m high minaret. The monuments testify to outstanding achievements in architecture and craftsmanship whose influence reached Iran and Afghanistan, and later the architecture of the Mogul Empire of 16th-century India. After our visit of KunyaUrgench we drive to the Turkmenistan-Uzbekistan border point at Khojeyli, where we go through border formalities on both checkpoints, whilst being an interesting experience they do lack modern facilities.  A short drive viewing the countryside gets us to Nukus – a place that is almost lost in the middle of the desert.'
}, {
  "title": 'Grand Abdi Malik Hotel, Khiva',
  "lat": '41.377115',
  "lng": '60.3580361',
  "description": 'DAY 05 Morning we visit the SavitskyKarakalpakstan Art Museum, which hosts the worlds second largest collection of Russian avant-garde art applied arts objects. It is also home to one of the largest collections of archeological objects and folk, applied and contemporary art originating from Central Asia. Drive through rural Uzbekistan to the historical city of Khiva. Here we explore the Ichan-Kala - the inner town (protected by brick walls some 10 m high) of the old Khiva oasis, which was the last resting-place of caravans before crossing the desert to Iran. Although few very old monuments still remain, it is a coherent and well-preserved example of the Muslim architecture of Central Asia. There are several outstanding structures such as the Djuma Mosque, the mausoleums and the madrasas and the two magnificent palaces built at the beginning of the 19th century by Alla-Kulli-Khan. Dinner at the popular Yassaulbashi restaurant.'
}, {
  "title": 'Omar Khayyam Hotel, Bukhara',
  "lat": '39.7703649',
  "lng": '64.4149347',
  "description": 'DAY 06 - DAY 07 A short drive to Urgench the capital of Khorezm province. It has a population of 150,000 inhabitants. We will have a drive through of the city before talking our flight to the historical Silk Road city of Bukhara. Upon arrival at Bukhara the most well known of the Silk Road oasis dating back to over 2,000 years. It is the most complete example of a medieval city in Central Asia, with an urban fabric that has remained largely intact. Monuments of particular interest include the famous tomb of Ismail Samani, a masterpiece of 10th-century Muslim architecture, and a large number of 17th-century madrasas. Afternoon we enjoy a walking tour of Bukhara, visiting several mosques, madrasas and the hat seller’s market. Evening we enjoy a folklore show at the Devanbegi Madrasa. End the day the Bukharan style with dinner enjoying Bukharan cuisine at the Minzifa Restaurant located in the Old Town. DAY 07 Today we continue our tour through the Historic Centre of Bukhara*, which houses over 140 architectural monuments. Bukhara had narrow streets will remind us of the Arabian Nights. After seeing the historical sites we visit Akbar’s Gallery where one can seea rich collection of old carpets and suzzane – his display center is like a museum assisted by UNESCO – his collection is well known to the Metropolitan Museum.   To culminate our Bukhara experience we visit a miniaturist house where we see the workshop of the painters and his students all trying to retain the traditional art. Miniature painting was introduced here from Persia and the same tradition continued for many years but is facing its challenges with modernity.   We join in for a home cooked meal.'
}, {
  "title": 'Grand Samarkand Hotel, Samarkand',
  "lat": '39.6725002',
  "lng": '66.9364854',
  "description": 'DAY 08 - DAY 09 Yet another tour of the historical city visiting the SitoraiMokhi-Khosa Palace followed by the residence of the Emir of Bukhara, the Mausoleum of the Sufi BakhoutdinNaqshbandi and the ChorBakr Necropolis. As we continue to Samarkand we stop atGijduvon to visit a famous madrassa built by Ulugh Beg the Timurid Sultan, astronomer and mathematician. We also visit the tomb and memorial of the prominent philosopher AbduholikGijduvoni, after whom the city is named.  An interesting insight to the arts of Uzbekistan as we visit the famous pottery works of Alisher well known for his unique style and color. Past famous visitors include Prince Charles, Lady Diana and Hillary Clinton.  Arrival Samarkand late afternoon. Evening, after some free time to stroll through the lanes of this historical city we are treated to dinner at the famous Old City Restaurant of Samarkand. DAY 09 This day is dedicated to explore the Historic town of Samarkand* - a crossroad and melting pot of the worlds cultures. Founded in the 7th century B.C. as ancient Afrasiab, Samarkand had its most significant development in the Timurid period from the 14th to the 15th centuries. The major monuments include the Registan Mosque and madrasas, Bibi-Khanum Mosque, the Shakhi-Zinda compound and the Gur-Emir ensemble, as well as Ulugh-Begs Observatory. Time permitting we visit a family home to learn how the most popular Uzbek meal, the pulao, is cooked. Evening is free and you may visit the local Afghan carpet makers, the local winery, the Kunhil paper makers or just back into time.'
}, {
  "title": 'ShakreSabz Star Hotel, Shakhrisyabz',
  "lat": '39.0400391',
  "lng": '66.8069597',
  "description": 'DAY 10 Morning we tour the Afrosiyob Museum and the tomb of Saint Daniel. Then we drive to KoniGhil village to see the traditional way of making Samarkand paper from mulberry leaves.   Continue to the Historic Centre of Shakhrisyabz*, the birthplace of Tamerlane. The city contains a collection of exceptional monuments and ancient quarters that bear witness to the citys secular development, and particularly to the period of its apogee, under the rule of Amir Temur and the Temurids, in the 15th-16th century. Dinner will be a local experience at Alisher’s House. Evening free.'
}, {
  "title": 'Serena Hotel, Dushanbe',
  "lat": '38.5142164',
  "lng": '68.7511861',
  "description": 'DAY 11 - DAY 12 An early morning departure as we drive to the capital city of Tajikistan. Upon arrival at the border we first complete exit border formalities of Uzbekistan and then a short walk across to the Tajik side to do the entry border formalities. Change of vehicles as we drive to Dushanbe.  We arrive at Dushanbe and are transferred to our hotel. Tajikistan is a double landlocked country, which was part of the Soviet Union and now has a Presidential form of government. It has a population of 8 million.  Evening we are treated to Turkish/Tajik local cuisine dinner at the Café Merve Turkish. DAY 12 Our day in Dushanbe is spent visiting the National Museum of Tajikistan, the Gurminj Musical Instruments Museum, Statue of Ismail Samani and Rudaki Park. Subject to permit we also visit the recently built and an architectural marvel, the IsmailiJamatkhan and Centre.  Lunch is at the Traktir Restaurant known for its speciality of Ukranian cuisine. We then visit the Botanical Gardens and culminate with an experience of the local bazaar. Evening is free to stroll the street and meet the friendly Tajiks at the teahouses.'
}, {
  "title": 'Lotte Hotel, Tashkent',
  "lat": '41.309827',
  "lng": '69.2665513',
  "description": 'DAY 13 We explore Uzbekistan’s capital visiting the Old City, including the Khast-Imom Complex where the world famous Quran of Caliph Uthman/Ottoman has been preserved, the Madrasah of Barak-Khan, Tilla Sheikh Mosque, the Mausoleum of the Saint Abu BakrKaffalShashi, the Islamic Institute of Imam al-Bukhari and explore Chor-Su Bazaar. An evening flight gets us to the largest and until recently the capital city of Kazakhstan. Upon arrival at Alma Aty we are welcomed and transferred to our hotel.'
}, {
  "title": 'Otrar Hotel, Almaty',
  "lat": '43.2608189',
  "lng": '76.9495966',
  "description": 'DAY 14 An early morning departure as we drive to the capital city of Tajikistan. Upon arrival at the border we first complete exit border formalities of Uzbekistan and then a short walk across to the Tajik side to do the entry border formalities. Change of vehicles as we drive to Dushanbe.  We arrive at Dushanbe and are transferred to our hotel. Tajikistan is a double landlocked country, which was part of the Soviet Union and now has a Presidential form of government. It has a population of 8 million.  Evening we are treated to Turkish/Tajik local cuisine dinner at the Café Merve Turkish.'
}, {
  "title": 'Ak-Keme Hotel, Bishkek',
  "lat": '42.8375965',
  "lng": '74.5818513',
  "description": 'DAY 15 We start early today on what is going to be a long day. Our tour begins with a visit to the Panfilov Park, followed by Zenkov Cathedral, St. Nicholas Cathedral and the Green Bazaar. From here we drive through Chang an-Tianshan Corridor*. We visit the Petroglyphs within the Archaeological Landscape of Tamgaly*. Set around the lush Tamgaly Gorge, amidst the vast, arid Chu-Ili Mountains, is a remarkable concentration of some 5,000 petroglyphs (rock carvings) dating from the second half of the second millennium BC to the beginning of the 20th century. Distributed among 48 complexes with associated settlements and burial grounds, they are testimonies to the husbandry, social organization and rituals of pastoral peoples. From here we drive to the border to Kyrgyzstan and continue to our hotel in Bishkek. Known alsos as Furunze, Bishkek is the capital city of Kyrgyzstan. Lunch will be at the Arzu Restaurant.'
}, {
  "title": 'Four Seasons Karven Resort, IssykKul Lake',
  "lat": '42.6035605',
  "lng": '76.936764',
  "description": 'DAY 16 - DAY 18 We enjoy our tour of Bishkek, which includes visits to Oak Park, Ala-Too Square, Statue of Manas, the Philharmonic Hall and Victory Monument. Drive to Balasagun and visit the historical Burana Tower*, which dates back to the 9th century AD. We will also visit the nearby museum. We then proceed eastwards into the mountains to Cholpon-Ata where we visit the local rock drawings of the Bronze periods, the local museum and a small local bazaar before arriving at our resort at Central Asia’s most popular will known resort. The Four Season’s Karven is known also for its impressive views of the imposing alpine ranges of the Tian Shan across the lake. For the balance of the day we have optional opportunities to walk around the valley and enjoy some of the boat rides being offered at the enchanting IssykKul Lake. Evening we enjoy dinner at a local restaurant attached to the Lake. DAY 17 Morning we visit the Preshevalsky Museum and Monument on the eastern edge of the Lake. A landmark museum, dedicated to the memory of Nikolai MichailovichPreshevalsky, who was an enthusiastic explorer accredited for his excellent works on the flora and fauna of the region. In the afternoon we visit the Annanaeva village where we get the opportunity to hike and visit local families and see their yurt accommodation and enjoy soup and tea with them. Evening for dinner we taste the cuisine of yet another of the popular restaurants at the IssykKul Lake. DAY 18 Enjoy our time at the lake. Afternoon we drive to Bishkek and enjoy a farewell dinner at Captain Nemo Restaurant.  We are then transferred to the airport and after an enjoyable trail following the Central Asian portion of the Silk Road, we bid farewell to the land of the Stans.'
}, ];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```